# Разный шрифт в ячейках таблицы

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word

Пытаюсь в `Qt` взаимодействовать с `Word`.

Как сделать чтобы в одной ячейки таблицы печатался текст в одном формате, а ниже в другом

И как сделать, чтоб ниже был шрифт курсив?

вот код

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QAxObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QAxObject *pword = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
    //интерфейс к подобъекту - коллекция скрытых документов
    QAxObject* pdoc = pword->querySubObject("Documents()");
    //создаем новый документ
    pdoc = pdoc->querySubObject("Add()");

    // QAxObject *font = pdoc->querySubObject("Range()");
    QAxObject *prange = pdoc->querySubObject("Range()");
    QAxObject *prange1 = pdoc->querySubObject("Range()");
    QAxObject *tables = pdoc->querySubObject("Tables()");
    QAxObject *rangeTable1 = pdoc->querySubObject("Range()");
    rangeTable1->dynamicCall("SetRange(int, int)", 0, 50);
    QAxObject* table1 = tables->querySubObject("Add(Range, NumRows, NumColumns, DefaultTableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior)",
                                       rangeTable1->asVariant(), 9, 3, 1, 1);
    //Заполняем таблицу
    //горизонтальные заголовки
    QAxObject *currentCell = table1->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)", 1, 1);
    QAxObject *currentCell1 = table1->querySubObject("Cell(Row, Column)", 1, 1);
    prange = currentCell->querySubObject("Range()");

     prange1 = currentCell1->querySubObject("Range()");
    prange->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)","rtt \n");

    QAxObject *pfont = prange->querySubObject("Font");
    pfont->setProperty("Size", 20);



    prange1->dynamicCall("InsertAfter(Text)", 023);



    QAxObject *pfont1 = prange1->querySubObject("Font");
    pfont1->setProperty("Size", 5);

    pword->setProperty("Visible", true);
```

Что-то я делаю не так, раз весь текст получается только в формате, который внизу

что хочу получить: чтоб текст в ячейках был разный
[image: что хочу получить, чтоб текст в ячейках был разный]

что получается:
[image: что получается]

Comment: Отформатируйте код и опишите ожидаемый/реальный вывод